# pwm or gpio for pled display on beagle bone?

Tags: pwm, gpio, beaglebone-black, oled

Wondering which adafruit bbio library i should use. I know nothing. My sense is that GPIO will be simpler to  communicate the display info to the screen. The screen is a 128x32 adafruit pled

Comment: Thanks Scott, I assumed PWM was going to be unnecessary. I actually asked because the device i'm using is the adafruit ssd1306 oled display, and adafruit gave the option of using a pwm or gpio library. Now I'm given the task of programming to achieve the same functionality in javascript since that is the overarching program our BBB is going to run.

Comment: If its http://www.adafruit.com/products/938?gclid=CjkKEQjwwbCcBRCxvJn9-N6dorwBEiQAVriOignNRBhb2vJOVuOFWMlGaaNkzjEhBSbYcZsb12rYvCzw_wcB, then it communicates via I2C or SPI.  I suggest SPI will be easier to bit-bang than I2C if you're using the gpio library.  PWM is *probably* for brightness control

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you gave a link to the part.  Often, these have a predetermined bus type like SPI by which the device is intended to be controlled.  If you use GPIO to do this, you could certainly bit-bang it, but you might be better off looking at how to implement the appropriate protocol using the built in Beaglebone features.

PWM is a different beast.  It might be useful for controlling the backlight of the display.  I haven't seen such displays actually controlled by PWM before -- but again, if you post the part, I can be more specific.